# how to remove Flurry

Tags: ios, xcode, analytics, flurry

I have recently starting taking after my company's app. I want to remove flurry and put in MixPanels. I want to know is there a procedure in deleting Flurry, or just delete the .h file?
This is my first time working with analytics.

Comment: You can simply disable the setup lines in the app delegate.  (Or you can delete the .h file and go around deleting all the errors that pop up as a result.)

Comment: ahhh, thank you! its much easier this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"YOUR_APP_ID"];` from your AppDelegate.

You can/should also remove all the `#import "FlurryAnalytics.h"` inclusions as well as various Flurry calls, and the library itself (Build phases / Link Binary With Libraries) to reduce the 300K or so it adds to your app.